# How can I post data from react to sql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

When I try to post data it gives me `GET http://localhost:5000/stored 404 (Not Found)`. How can I post data and then store it in mysql database?

This is code in `React`

```
import React from 'react'
    class InsertProduct extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super( )
        }

   postData(){

    fetch('/stored', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            firstParam: 'yourValue',
            secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
        })
        })

   }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.postData()}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default InsertProduct;
```

And this is `node` and `express`

```
app.post('/stored', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.body)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to share some more of your code in order for me to know exactly what is wrong. But the error says it can't locate a GET method on the "/stored" endpoint on port 5000.

- You are sharing code for a POST endpoint, but your error message says GET. So something is weird there. You should double-check that that error message is occurring due to the post request.
- In your react code you just have fetch("/stored"...), is 5000 the correct port that your server is listening on?
- Another possible issue is maybe you have a bug in some express middleware code you didn't share.

For debugging, start by just logging a response from the endpoint:

```js
app.post('/stored', (req, res) => {
  res.send('POST request received');
})
```

Once you confirm you're getting that response as expected then move on to parsing the body of the req and sending it to your database.

Comment: Actually, problem was with my network. I did everything good in my code, but network gave me problems